# defining signal outside __init__ of class doesn't work?

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

I'm trying to understand signals and slots....

read a couple of things

http://www.harshj.com/2010/05/06/pyqt-faq-custom-signals-jpeg-mouse-hovers-and-more/#custom

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/

and here is the question:

```
class bla(object):
    blaSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

works but

class bla(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.blaSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

doesn't work and it states something about the signal not being bound...
What do I not understand here? Why does one work?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain exactly what "doesn't work" means, and show the exact error (with traceback) instead of just "something about the signal not being bound".

Comment: I'm assuming you understand the basic difference between class attributes and instance attributes, and just want to know why signals have to be class attributes. If you don't understand the first part either, there's more to answer…

Comment: yes I understand the basic difference but probably barely that... also reading up on that now

Comment: OK, good, that basic difference should be enough to understand why you need signals to be class attributes, so I think my answer should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you want there to be a single signal that's shared by all `bla` objects.

If you had a different signal for each `bla`, nobody would be able to connect up any signal without knowing about the particular `bla` instance that owned the particular signal. That would be bad enough within the program, but imagine how something like `QtDesigner` or the `QMetaObject`-based introspection would handle it. Even if it created a `bla` instance, that wouldn't be the same `bla` instance your code created at runtime.

This is somewhat explained in [Defining New Signals with `pyqtSignal()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal) in the docs.

Comment: ok most of this makes sense.. So basically, if two buttons were of class bla and I pressed one of them would both emit a signal?